# Sweep a string and insert portions into an array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have this string, inside the variable 'strings':

```
NSMutableArray *array_strings;
NSString *strings = @"one<-+->two<-+->three";
```

The separator string is "<-+->". I want to place certain words from the string within an array, as below:

- [0] -> one
- [1] -> two
- [3] -> three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
array_strings = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"<-+->"] mutableCopy];
```

Notes:

1. `array_strings` should really be named `arrayStrings`
2. `strings` should generally be named as a singular, not plural (plural would be used for collections)
3. Scan the methods on a class to see what's readily available ;-)